# Cancel dispose inside Dispose method

Tags: c#, dispose

Is there a way I can cancel a dispose from within the Dispose method, in other words NOT dispose A when A.Dispose() is called.

**Update**
I didn't explain well, 'cos I couldn't think of a way to put it nicely. What I have is a class that displays a progress bar (marquee) in a popup window that runs in a separate thread. When the progress popup is created, a controller-like disposable object is returned, so we can do something like this:

```
using (var progress = Dialogs.ShowProgress("Please wait..."))
{
    // do lots of stuff here
    progress.UpdateStatus("Please wait some more...");
    // do more stuff
}
```

when the using block exits, the progress window is closed and destroyed.

Now I have situations where things that happen within this block also create a progress window and instead of returning a new object and creating a new window, I wanted to return the object created by the first instance, and only destroy it once the first instance disposes.

**Update**
Ok, what I did was to create a new IDisposable object with each `Dialogs.ShowProgress()` call, and attached the original controller object to it. These objects get disposed of whenever they're done, and the controller only gets disposed when it's the only object left to dispose.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do that? Basically you're asking "I have this contract that says I must do X, but I don't want to - how do I get out of it?"

Comment: I smell framework abuse here. If the entire .NET framework doesn't have the need to cancel a Dispose() call do you think you really need to?

Comment: You are confusing the `Dispose` method, which is a convention (widely used across the .NET Framework, but not a language thing, just a convention), with a _finalizer_ (which has a different syntax), and _still_ you can't cancel a finalizer (which makes no sense)... the way to _"cancel"_ `Dispose` is just... not calling `Dispose`.

Comment: Sometimes using a `using` is not the best choice, you ran in to one of those situations. In your case I would replace the `using` block with a try-finally block so you can have more control to what happens to the object at the end of the block.

Comment: @Jcl: Actually there is a way to "cancel" a finalizer. When the GC categorizes a reference as "dead and needing finalization" it puts it in the finalizer queue, at which point it becomes "alive" again. If the finalizer causes the reference to the object to remain alive then you have a bona fide alive object again that the GC will not clean up until it is dead again. (And in fact, the object can mark itself as "treat me as though I was never finalized" if it wants the finalizer to run again the second time it is dead.)  These techniques are for advanced players only.

Comment: @EricLippert , believe it or not, I had heard about that technique (not that I know how to do it, have used it,  have had the need for it... or will ever have :-) )... can you do it with standard C# or do you need to fiddle with the IL?

Comment: @Jcl: You can do it with ordinary C#. Pooling strategies often use this technique. When the object is about to be released by the GC, the GC puts it on the finalizer queue and when the finalizer runs, it puts the object right back in the pool, making it alive, and tells the object "you still haven't been finalized" so that the *next time* it goes around this karmic cycle, it gets resurrected again.

Comment: I was under the impression that calling Dispose not only allows you to clean up your resources but also tells GC that the object can now be collected. I just wanted to NOT have the object collected until I'm ready to have it collected even if Dispose was called.

Comment: This is all pretty fishy.  But the simple way to do it is to add a CanDispose property.  Throw an exception when the client ignored it.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, it's a bad idea to implement `IDisposable` in a way that might not really dispose.  Here's an alternate way to implement what you're trying to do:

```
interface IMaybeDisposable
{
    bool TryDispose(); //return false if dispose was canceled
}
```

You might use it like:

```
IMaybeDisposable maybe = //something
try
{
    // do something with maybe
}
finally
{
    if (maybe.TryDispose())
        // yay, it disposed!
    else
        // hm, it didn't dispose; do something else
}
```

Comment: +1 This is actually a credible solution that avoids misplacing your object in `using`

Comment: +1 It is still questionable when someone would actually need this, but at least this interface clearly communicates what is going on.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I agree. Needing this points at bad design somewhere else

Comment: Perhaps rename the method `TryDispose` to make it clearer still that it's not the regular dispose.  As is one could easily call this `Dispose` and not realize there is a return value.

Comment: @Servy I like that, and have added that to my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Just don't do whatever you would have done to dispose the object.  You don't need to actively do anything special.

Be careful though; when someone disposes of an object they expect it to actually dispose of it's unmanaged resources, rather than ignoring you and holding into them anyway.

Comment: In what way does this not answer the question exactly as asked?

Comment: Oh, I'm not knocking you at all, @Servy - the OP question was my target there, sorry :)

Comment: @JerKimball Yep, that's why I didn't reply to you. It was directed at those downvoting the answer.

Comment: There, I can pop you back to null, at least :)

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful about doing this. If you cancel disposing a method at the end of a  using block, then you've lost the reference to that object and you'll never have a chance to have it dispose of its contents again, meaning that you could leak resources if you're not careful. In particular, I would only do this myself if the dispose method released references to large objects that I didn't want garbage collected right away for whatever reason. I wouldn't do this to skip releasing handles to files, database connections,  network sockets, or anything else that can't be garbage collected.

As the commenters pointed out, I would try to refactor my code so that whatever problem I was trying to solve by canceling the dispose would be solved some other, less dangerous way.

If you're absolutely sure that you have an edge condition where you need to skip disposing something, here's one way to do it:

```
public void Dispose()
{
     if(condition)
     {
         // do disposing stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: still horrible idea, despite the explanation. `using` doesn't support *conditionally disposable objects*

Comment: @StenPetrov `!condition` is itself a type of condition, so your code is exactly the same.

Comment: @StenPetrov: The answer shows how to do what the OP asks and then explains in detail why it is a bad idea. I don't really see what your comment is aimed at.

Comment: @Servy it's better because the object will not be conditionally disposable, and `using` will still work with it in case of Exception. I still think it's a bad idea tho, so I deleted the suggestion

Comment: @StenPetrov If you feel that a question is fundamentally flawed and solutions to it shouldn't be implemented then you should comment to the question itself explaining the inherent problems in the question, and suggesting a different approach, rather than criticizing answers for answering the question.

Comment: @Servy and I did that too. But there's a common 'expectation bias' which would still mislead a person who asked a question to pick up a wrong answer rather than considering their question being wrong

Comment: @StenPetrov If your goal was to convey that rather than having `Dispose` conditionally dispose of the object, the code should be refactored so that the caller simply conditionally calls dispose on that object, then you should say that, as you didn't convey it particularly clearly in your comment.  If that's what you meant, then I'd say that might be a valid solution, and it's certainly better than what the OP is asking, although without knowing the context it's hard to discuss what's truly appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The required post-condition for `Dispose` is that the client code should be able to abandon all references to the object without causing any necessary cleanup to go uncompleted.  If that condition applies before `Dispose` is called, then the `Dispose` method may legitimately do nothing.  If that condition does not apply, `Dispose` must make it do so, and may not legitimately return unless or until it does [note that `Dispose` need not actually perform the cleanup, if it sets in motion a chain of events via which the cleanup will occur at some later time].  Nothing in the contract for the `Dispose` interface allows it to sometimes leave objects in a state requiring further cleanup unless it has reason to believe that cleanup will occur via some other means.

Answer (score 0):

Based  on  your  update, I  would  do  something  like  this:

```
 public  void  DoStuff()
{
     DoPrepWork();
     using( var  controller =  TheMethodYouWroteThatShouldReturnAController())
    {
         DoStuffOverControllerLifetime();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but the stuff that's creating the nested usings could also be called elsewhere where they would then be the creators of the initial controller. Of course, I could also be misunderstanding your answer.